# Converting JavaScript to jQuery Clear Select & Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am refactoring some of my old JavaScript to jQuery and am struggling on transforming a couple of lines.

First off what I am trying to do is take `#titlestates` which is a select drop down and set the index back to 0, so that nothing has been chosen.

```
if (document.getElementById("titlestates")) {
  document.getElementById("titlestates").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

And Second, I am trying to take a checkbox `#brandnewrv` and uncheck it making it false.

```
document.getElementById("brandnewrv").checked = false;
```

**My failed attempt:**

```
$("#titlestates > select").val("");
$("#brandnewrv").prop(checked, false);
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$("#titlestates > select > option").eq(0).prop('selected', true);`

Comment: Why are you changing existing, working Javascript code to jQuery? jQuery is simply a plugin and is not needed. Adding jQuery while you do not really need it will only slow down your website performance.

Comment: I am refactoring it because there is a lot of jQuery already in it and I am trying to have it all the same to clean it up a bit instead of having half JavaScript and half jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#titlestates").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
$("#brandnewrv").prop('checked', false);
```